# Microsoft SQL Server - How to convert all `ntext` columns to `nvarchar(max)` in tables and views?

Tags: sql-server

I need to replace all `ntext` columns with `nvarchar(max)` in the entire database. In this case, you need to do this for all tables and for all views.
I have the following code which works great for tables but doesn't work for views:

```
-- Create a temporary table that will contain all tables containing fields of type ntext
CREATE TABLE #TablesToModify
(
    TableName NVARCHAR(255),
    ColumnName NVARCHAR(255)
)

-- Fill the temporary table with a list of tables and fields of type ntext
INSERT INTO #TablesToModify
SELECT c.TABLE_NAME, c.COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
WHERE c.DATA_TYPE = 'ntext'

-- Go through each table and ALTER TABLE to change the data type
DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @ColumnName NVARCHAR(255)

DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
SELECT TableName, ColumnName
FROM #TablesToModify

OPEN cur

FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @TableName, @ColumnName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    -- Execute ALTER TABLE to change the data type
    EXEC ('ALTER TABLE ' + @TableName + ' ALTER COLUMN ' + @ColumnName + ' NVARCHAR(MAX)')

    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @TableName, @ColumnName
END

CLOSE cur
DEALLOCATE cur

-- Delete temporary table
DROP TABLE #TablesToModify
```

What should I add to change the `ntext` column type to `nvarchar(max)` in views as well?

I found a solution on stackoverflow how to change all columns in tables but didn't find how to change them in views.
On the Internet, too, all information related to this topic refers only to tables.

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work for `VIEW`s" `VIEW`s `SELECT` from objects, the column has the underlying data type of the column from the object. It's the underlying object you need to `ALTER`. After you `ALTER` the objects, you then need to refresh any `VIEW`s that used that column.

Comment: I already have views in the database, with a lot of data. One of the columns in the view is of type `ntext`. I need to extend my script so that it traverses not only tables but also views by changing the `ntext` type of the view column to `nvarchar(max)`.

Comment: just run exec sys.sp_refreshsqlmodule  on all views after you're done with the tables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to call `sp_refreshview` or `sp_refreshsqlmodule` on each view that references these tables. You can get this information out of `sys.sql_expression_dependencies`

- You need to add the schema name also.
- Object names should be `sysname`.
- Don't use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` it's for compatibility only and can be unreliable.
- You need to maintain nullability of the column.
- Cursors on system tables can be iffy. Either use a `STATIC` cursor, or better just generate one big SQL script using `STRING_AGG`.

```sql
CREATE TABLE #TablesToModify
(
    ObjectId bigint,
    SchemaName sysname,
    TableName sysname,
    ColumnName sysname,
    IsNullable bit
);

-- Fill the temporary table with a list of tables and fields of type ntext
INSERT INTO #TablesToModify (ObjectId, SchemaName, TableName, ColumnName, IsNullable)
SELECT
  t.object_id, s.name, t.name, c.name, c.is_nullable
FROM sys.columns c
JOIN sys.types typ ON typ.user_type_id = c.user_type_id
JOIN sys.tables t ON t.object_id = c.object_id
JOIN sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
WHERE typ.name = 'ntext';

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);

SELECT @sql = STRING_AGG(CAST(CONCAT(
    'ALTER TABLE ',
    QUOTENAME(SchemaName),
    '.',
    QUOTENAME(TableName),
    ' ALTER COLUMN ',
    QUOTENAME(ColumnName),
    ' NVARCHAR(MAX)',
    IIF(IsNullable = 1, N' NOT NULL;', N';')
  ) AS nvarchar(max)), ';
'  )
FROM #TablesToModify;


SELECT @sql += '
' + STRING_AGG(CAST(CONCAT(
    'EXEC sp_refreshsqlmodule ''',
    REPLACE(QUOTENAME(s.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(o.name), '''', ''''''),
    ''''
  ) AS nvarchar(max)), '
'  )
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT ObjectId
    FROM #TablesToModify
) t
JOIN sys.sql_expression_dependencies d ON d.referenced_id = t.ObjectId
JOIN sys.objects o ON o.object_id = d.referencing_id
JOIN sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = o.schema_id
GROUP BY
  d.referencing_id;


PRINT @sql;  -- your friend

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;


-- Delete temporary table
DROP TABLE #TablesToModify
```

Comment: Your code is throwing an error and I can't figure out what the problem is:
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near 'NULLEXEC'.

Comment: @Dmytro, try adding a semi-colon statement terminator:  `IIF(IsNullable = 1, N' NOT NULL;', N';')`

Comment: Have fixed it now